# Panads: Trying to manipulate Data

Tags: pandas

I have a large data file i am trying to clean up and then analyze. I have the following code which organizes the data how i need it to be.

import pandas as pd

header_list = ['Time']

df = pd.read_csv('S8-1.csv' , skiprows=6 , names = header_list)

df[['Date/Time','Pressure']] = df.Time.str.split(",,", expand=True)

df.pop('Time')

df

When I try to do this:

```
df.loc[(df['Pressure'] > 100 )]
```

I am getting an errro because my pressure column is not in numeric. What is the easiest way to convert only this one column to numeric while also keeping the column name?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Answer (score -2):

```
df[['Pressure']] = df[['Pressure']].astype(int)
```

Using `astype()` before you try to compare the column values should do the trick.